# What is the "container" keyword in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I recently inherited a code base with some Jenkins files. In one of them I ran into this syntax

```
            stage('Prepare database for integration tests') {
                steps {
                    container('postgres') {
                        sh "..."
                    }
                }
            }
```

Our Jenkins is running on Openshift and the pod has multiple containers including this postgres one. However I can't find any references for using the container or connecting to a container with `container('containerName')` like that.

I tried to create a separate pipeline with the following piece

```
                        container('az-cli') {
                            try {
                                sh 'ls'
                            } catch (error) {
                                throw error
                            }
                        }
```

And `ls` listed the content in the code repository - not the container. Clearly `container` is not doing what I thought it does and I can't find any documentation on it. Does anyone know what this is supposed to do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ok, It apparently comes from the Kubernetes plugin. More documentation is in this [jenkins github repo](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin) and in this [jenkins documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/kubernetes/#-container-run-build-steps-in-a-container).

And also it was working but the 'ls' command was deceiving. When I ran an actual Azure command I saw the command result also see the logs of the container.

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1):

If the container(...) method is not documented it is likely being loaded by a custom *[library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/)*.

Check for the @Library annotation in your pipeline or if it is not part of an automatically loaded lib. You'll then find the groovy file where it is declared.

More info at https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#using-libraries

Comment: I didn't think this is a custom function because the file doesn't have any imports. Actually it does, but nothing that can contain the 'container' keyword. I found the answer. Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a container to run a step, you can do like it : https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#using-multiple-containers

I never saw the "container" keyword before.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found and posted the answer.